# flutter voice command without button

Tags: flutter

Im looking to be able to control my app with voice.
the catch is, the solutiosn i found today in pub.dev and forums works this way

1. a button is pressed
2. microphone is activated and you got a few seconds to say the command you need
3. speect to text
4. command executed

what i need is like this

1. app launch
2. it kept listening and waiting to very specific commands such as close , pause, resume
3. when it detects those very very specific one word command it would do it.

basically, i want the interaction of such as 'Hi siri', 'ok google' but instead of that i want 'pause'

can anyone recommend a solution

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you make use of platform specific code. I use Java to interact with my flutter app. As soon as you achieve this, you could specify certain actions on detection of any of the action words.

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  SpeechRecognition _speechRecognition;
  bool _isAvailable = false;
  bool _isListening = false;

  String resultText = "";

  static const platform = const MethodChannel("com.example.javaConnect/javaConnect");


  void test() async {
    String value; 

    try{
      value = await platform.invokeMethod("startService"); // startService is the method used in the Java code
    }catch (e){
      print(e);
    }

    print(value);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initSpeechRecognizer();
    if (_isAvailable && !_isListening) {
      _speechRecognition.listen(locale: "en_US")
      .then(
        (result) => print('$result'),
      );
    }
  }

  void initSpeechRecognizer() {
    _speechRecognition = SpeechRecognition();

    _speechRecognition.setAvailabilityHandler(
        (bool result) => setState(() => _isAvailable = result));

    _speechRecognition.setRecognitionStartedHandler(
        () => setState(() => _isListening = true));

    _speechRecognition.setRecognitionResultHandler(
      (String speech) {
        setState(() => resultText = speech);
        if ( speech == "no no no" ){
            test();
        }  
      }
    );

    _speechRecognition.setRecognitionCompleteHandler(
        () {
          setState(() => _isListening = false);
        });

    _speechRecognition.activate().then(
          (result) => setState(() => _isAvailable = result),
        );

    final String number = "123456789";
  }

  void filterVoicings(String result) {
    print(result);
  }

  void recallMethod(){
    Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
      if (_isAvailable && !_isListening) {
        _speechRecognition.listen(locale: "en_US")
            .then(
              (result) => print('$result'),
        ).catchError((error) => print('$error'));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text(resultText),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    recallMethod();
                  },
                  child: Text("Listen"),
                  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_isListening) {
                      _speechRecognition.stop()
                      .then(
                            (result) => setState(() => _isListening = result)
                          );
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text("Stop"),
                  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a link to a video to properly explain using flutter with native code. [Flutter with native code (Android Java)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXuAzXY_KOo&t=121s)